# JQuery Mobile: Jump from an external page on an anchor at a page (from index.html to services.html)?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following link in the external html file "index.html":

```
<a href="service.html#collapsible_container1">Go to anchor</a>
```

On the page "services.html" there are several collapsible div container.

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" class="xy" id="collapsible_container1">
      <h2>Collapsible Container 1</h2>
      ...
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" class="xy" id="collapsible_container2">
      <h2>Collapsible Container 2</h2>
      ...
    </div>
```

How can I jump to a spesific collapsible container an expand it?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this. One way is to use data-attributes and script to change pages.

In the anchor tags, use a data-attribute to store the id of the collapsible you want to navigate to:

```
  <a id="btnAnchor" class="btnanchor" data-collapsibleid="collapsible_container2" href="#">Go to second collapsible</a><br />
  <a id="btnAnchor2" class="btnanchor" data-collapsibleid="collapsible_container1" href="#">Go to first collapsible</a><br />
  <a id="btnAnchor3" class="btnanchor" data-collapsibleid="" href="#">Go to page</a>
```

Then, when the user clicks on an anchor, use script to get the collapsible id, save it (i am using a global variable, you could use localStorage, pass as param, etc.) and navigate to the page:

```
  var selectedCollapsible = "";

   $(document).on("pagecreate","#index", function(){ 
    $(".btnanchor").on("click", function(e){
      selectedCollapsible = $(this).jqmData("collapsibleid");
      $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer( "change", "service.html" );
    });
  });
```

Finally,on the pageshow event, if service is shown, check for the collapsible id and if it exists, expand the collapsible and scroll to it:

```
 $( document ).on( "pagecontainershow" , function ( e, ui ) {
      if ( ui.toPage[0].id == "service" ) {
        if (selectedCollapsible && selectedCollapsible.length > 0) {
          //scroll to and expand that collapsible
          var $col = $("#" + selectedCollapsible);
          if ($col.length > 0){
            $col.collapsible( "expand" );
            var top = $col.offset().top;
            $.mobile.silentScroll( top );
          }
          selectedCollapsible = "";
        }
      }
  });
```

## **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q4jOdOqS7p9Czhegj1nS?p=preview)**

Comment: Is it possible to jump to the anchor on different html pages? I imagine an index, where I have several links to different pages.

Comment: Like this:
<form class="ui-filterable">
<input id="myFilter" data-type="search" />
</form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-autodividers="true">
<li><a href="id-1234.html#collapsible_container1" rel="external">Index value 1</a></li>
<li><a href="id-1235.html#any_content" rel="external">Index value 2</a></li>
<li><a href="id-1236.html#collapsible_container3" rel="external">Index value 3</a></li>
<li>...<li>
...
</ul>

Comment: @S.Braun, if you are using rel="external", then localStorage might be the way to go. Here is a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/cILYoYtLfKcTL2PqnbxB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is an elegant solution. In Firefox and Chrome it works perfectly. But on Ipad and in Internet Explorer it does not work.

Comment: @S.Braun, for me the plunker runs fine in Internet Explorer 11 on Win7

Comment: You're right. In Windows 7, it seems to work. This is probably the case at Windows 10.